# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null while invoking public java.lang.String JaxRS server

Tags: rest, url, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, query-string

```
@GET
@Path("/freePlaces")
@Produces("application/json")
public String places(@QueryParam("projectionId") String projectionId) {
    return projectionDAO.findById(Long.parseLong(projectionId)).getPlaces().toString();
}
```

I have this simple method and when I write in the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/cinema/rest/projection/freePlaces?projectionId=351
```

I get this exception :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null
>   while invoking public java.lang.String
>   cinema.services.ProjectionManager.places(java.lang.String) with params
>   [351]. org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null while invoking public
>   java.lang.String
>   cinema.services.ProjectionManager.places(java.lang.String) with params
>   [351].

I need some help how to resolve this.